# When is the right time to branch and when is the wrong time?

Tags: version-control, branch

Is there a specific rule I should be using for when to branch in source control? Branches seem to be expensive because they require that the team have extra knowledge about where the features they want to work on should go.

Our development team sometimes finds itself working on a long term feature and a shorter term feature at the same time. That means we end up with:

Trunk
-Branch A (Short Term)
-Branch B (Long Term)

After they complete we have to merge A in to the trunk, then merge the changes to the trunk back in to B to make sure those edits still function. It's messy.

I am wondering if we can cut down on branches by using Labels (Or tags, or pins or whatever your Source Control Software of choice calls it).  Maybe it makes sense to branch for the longer term project, but we could just do the edits for the short term project right in the trunk after applying a label to the stable release. That way we can always retrieve the source code that was stable if we have to do an emergency bug fix, but we don't have to deal with the branch.

What rules do you use to decide when to branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to reduce branching is to implement new features (especially smaller ones) directly on trunk. This is how we do it:

- small features, which will are guaranteed to be completed before the next release, are implemented on trunk
- for larger features, we create a feature branch ("Branch B" in your example)
- once we are ready to create a release, we create a release branch (from trunk), e.g. named "branches/2.x". This branch is then used for testing and finalizing the release.
- once the release is built, we tag the corresponding revision from the release branch (e.g. tags/2.0.0).
- normal development then continues on the trunk. the release branch is used for maintenance of the 2.x line of the product (e.g. bug fixes are merged from trunk, or implemented directly on that branch)

Answer (score 1):

In a small team, the time to branch is when you can't commit directly into the trunk. With svn (as I guess with other version controls as well), it is possible to postpone the decision to branch till the time one realizes that one cannot commit into the trunk.

To minimize the need to branch, a new feature can be worked on in the trunk itself by restricting the new-feature code within compile-time or run-time flags. This approach also allows to later turn off feature if not needed, do A/B split testing experiments with the feature, etc.

Of course with this approach it always helps to have a continuous testing that gives an early alert whenever the build/test-suite breaks on the trunk.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, this depends on the tool you use. Branches are more 'expensive' in Subversion than in Mercurial or git, because merges are harder to do. For another, it depends on your project/organization: you should probably have at least one branch per maintained version.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the VCS you are using.  If you are using a tool that has good support for merging, then you should branch whenever you feel like it.  When in doubt, create a new branch.  If the UNIX epoch time is even, then you should branch.  If it's, odd, you should wait a second, and then branch.  If you are using a tool that doesn't support merging well, then you should consider changing tools.  In other words, stop using a tool that makes it necessary to ask this question.

Answer (score -1):

It’s normally poor practice to develop against the mainline or trunk. The trunk should be used as the master code set and should reflect the code that currently represents production. If you are not in production yet, it should represent the gold copy and should always build and be subjected to automated regression tests. It should not be used to show development status or activity. Protect your trunk from change and resist the temptation to allow developers to check out and lock code on a trunk. The only updates in my view should be via the merge process, when you are ready to repatriate your code to the mainline.
When branching you should consider the purpose, complexity and duration of the development. 
•   Is it to support a team of developers working on a new feature or a substantial piece of development? 
•   Are you using traditional processes or the various  agile flavors that are out there? 
•   It is to accommodate the development of a patch or fix for production? 
•   What development and in particular, test activity will you accommodate on the branch and will you retain the branch until the derived artifacts are built, tested and deemed releasable?

There are many models out there but few give sufficient consideration to the "build" process and the implications of regenerating your releasable artifacts.

Let’s assume you have the following lifecycle: DEV->SYSTEM-INTEGRATIONTEST->UAT->PRE-PROD->PRODUCTION.  Assume you create a branch from mainline to accommodate the development and build processes. Your development\build\test cycle continues right through to UAT. The artifacts produced from this branch have been exposed to sufficient testing to deem them potentially suitable for release. You are able to state that the artifacts signed off by the users were also exposed to system and integration testing.

Some folks advocate merging the source code to the trunk at this point and recommend that you create a RELEASE branch upon a successful trunk rebuild. For me this is fine if the solution is stable and requires no further change prior to production, otherwise you risk propagating bugs elsewhere. In variably it will need to change.

If you do unearth issues in PRE_PROD, where are these “Fix” changes going to be made? Many suggest that you can make the code changes directly in the release branch. If you proceed, this modification will produce a new build and a new set of artifacts. You may elect to push these artifacts back through PRE_PROD and on to production, as the underlying code has been validated through previous  testing and the modifications made to stabilize the release are deemed risk free? But you have a problem.

You cannot state that the executables\artefacts released to pre-prod and subsequently production, have been tested in your lower environments. Despite confidence being high, the output from the release branch build is different from that produced from the development builds. This may fail audit.

Branching for me is about managing your code and not the build output or solely the release. If you advocate branching for release and release stabilization (pre-prod fixing), you must take the above risk combined with the need for significant regression testing into consideration.

On the basis that the trunk should represent production code, you cannot push code to it unless it has been pushed to production first. I advocate creating a branch that supports the development, build and release as a single cycle. To avoid branch longevity and unnecessary divergence from the trunk (and potential big bang conflict issues) limit the development as much as you can and release and repatriate often with the trunk to keep other development efforts current.